# How do I change a character embedded in file names to another character?

Tags: windows-xp, file-management, batch-rename

In a directory with multiple sub directories, I need to change file names that have the `_` character to a another character: `.`, for example:

```
ABC12345_DEF --> ABC12345.DEF
```

I need to do this recursively through a directory tree.
The last three characters of the file name are not always the same.

Using rename wildcards on either side of the `_` or `.` doesn't work (plus I need to do this through several directories).

Comment: Operating system?

Comment: possible duplicate http://superuser.com/questions/205083/command-line-recursive-rename-move-in-windows

Comment: Windows XP.  The last three characters are not the same on the files

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following should work.  I used `move` instead of `ren` due to the peculiarities of `ren` in handling filenames in quotes.

```
for /f "tokens=1,2 delims=_" %i in ( 'dir /s/b *_*.' ) do @( move "%i_%j" "%i.%j" )
```

You can remove the `@` if you'd like to visually track the progress of the command.

Comment: Can I put this as written in a BAT file for future use? or do I need to add something to make it work ... I really appreciate your help!

Comment: To make it work in a batch file, you need to change all of the variables that use a single percent sign to a double percent sign; i.e. change all instances of `%i` to `%%i` and `%j` to `%%j`.

Comment: Since `dir /s/b` returns the complete **path** and filename, `ren` would fail because `ren` doesn't like the second argument `%i.%j` to contain a path. Move likes it just fine.

Comment: Since the delimiter equals "`_`" (`delims=_`) , and "`dir /s/b`" returns the complete path and filename, this solution would fail if any part of the path contains one or more of "`_`" (underscore). This solution will also fail if the filename contains more than one of "`_`" because the full filename would not be represented by `%i` and `%j`.

Answer (score 1):

This batch file should do it for you.

Copy the batch file below into a text file and save it as xrename.cmd (or "whatever you want.cmd").

If you just run the file like this:
xrename.cmd

It will look in the current folder and all subfolders, and rename all files like: ABC12345_DEF to ABC12345.DEF (anything like "text_moretext" to "text.moretext").

You can also provide values for "search-string", "replace-string", and "search-pattern" on the command line.

To show instructions, run it like this:
xrename.cmd /help

**Note:** I made the batch file to only display the files that will be renamed, **no renaming** will actually take place.  You can run the batch file and see what will happen without actually renaming anything. Once you have run it and are confident the correct files will be properly renamed, you can delete the line as described below to make renaming active, then run the batch file again.

You might have to modify the value of "search-pattern" to display the files you want.

At the labels ":default1" and ":default2", you can edit the values for "match-string" "search-pattern" and "replace-string" to suit your needs.

This batch file has some error checking and it won't fail if the "match-string" is found in the names of any of the folders or subfolders.

```
@echo off

if "%~1%~2%~3."=="." goto :default1
if /i "%~1."=="/help." goto :syntax
if "%~1."=="." goto :syntax

rem %2 can be empty to use "*matchstring*" as the "search-pattern"
rem %3 can be empty to make replacement with empty string (delete matchstring).

set "matchstring=%~1"
set "replacestring=%~3"

if "%~2."=="." goto :default2
set "searchpattern=%~2"
goto :start

:default1
set "matchstring=_"
set "replacestring=."

:default2
set "searchpattern=*%matchstring%*"

:start
set "renamecount=0"
set "errorcount=0"

echo.
for /r %%f in ("%searchpattern%") do call :work "%%~dpf" "%%~nxf"
echo.
if %renamecount% EQU 0 echo No files renamed.
if %renamecount% EQU 1 echo Renamed %renamecount% file.
if %renamecount% GEQ 2 echo Renamed %renamecount% files.

if %errorcount% EQU 1 echo %errorcount% error renaming files.
if %errorcount% GEQ 2 echo %errorcount% errors renaming files.
echo.

goto :cleanexit

:work
set matchedfilepath=%~1
set matchedfilename=%~2

rem You can't do it directly like this:
rem set "newfilename=%matchedfilename:%matchstring%=%replacestring%%"

for /F "usebackq delims=" %%g in (`echo set "newfilename=%%matchedfilename:%matchstring%=%replacestring%%%"`) do %%g
echo In path "%matchedfilepath%": Renaming "%matchedfilename%" to "%newfilename%"




rem delete the next line (goto :EOF) to make renaming active
goto :EOF




ren "%matchedfilepath%%matchedfilename%" "%newfilename%"
if %errorlevel% NEQ 0 goto :workerror
if not exist "%matchedfilepath%%newfilename%" goto :workerror
goto :workok

:workerror
echo Rename "%matchedfilepath%%matchedfilename%" failed.
set /A errorcount=errorcount+1
echo.
goto :EOF

:workok
set /A renamecount=renamecount+1
goto :EOF

:syntax
rem:syntax
echo.
echo Syntax:
echo    %~nx0 ["match-string" ["search-pattern"] ["replace-string"]]
echo.
echo    Search for files matching "search-pattern" in current folder and through all 
echo    subfolders.  For each matched file, rename file by replacing "match-string" 
echo    with "replace-string".
echo.
echo    If "replace-string" is empty or not specified, rename file by deleting 
echo    "match-string".
echo.
echo    If "search-pattern" is empty, use "*matchstring*" as the "search-pattern".
echo.
echo    If "match-string" "search-pattern" and "replace-string" are all empty or not 
echo    specified, then defined defaults will be used.
echo.
echo    If "search-pattern" and/or "replace-string" are NOT empty then "match-string" 
echo    cannot be empty, 
echo.
goto :EOF

:cleanexit
set "matchstring="
set "replacestring="
set "searchpattern="
set "renamecount="
set "errorcount="
set "matchedfilepath="
set "matchedfilename="
set "newfilename="
goto :EOF
```

Once you have run the batch file and are confident the correct files will be properly renamed, you can edit the file to remove the line(s) described to make renaming active, then run the batch file again.

To do that, find the two lines that are like this:

```
rem delete the next line (goto :EOF) to make renaming active
goto :EOF
```

Then, remove the line that says "goto :EOF" (or remove both lines).

Don't remove "goto :EOF" from any other place in the batch file (it can be found in a few places so be sure to remove the correct one).

If this isn't working for you, or if you want me to explain anything in the batch file, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

modifying what I found at [this batch rename/move script](https://superuser.com/questions/205083/command-line-recursive-rename-move-in-windows) this should work:

```
for /r %x in (*_*) do ren "%x" *.*
```

Comment: it echos the full pathname in quotes followed by *.* but the names in the directories are unchanged