# Recursively renaming .foo files based on name of accompanying .bar file in multiple folders in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, rename, recursive

I've just finished creating SHA1 hashes for each album in my MP3 collection using Corz Checksum. It left a .hash file in each folder, as desired. (Each folder is an album.)

However, the hash files it generated all have the name of the folder, for example

> The Beatles - 1966 - Revolver.hash

I would like to **automatically rename all of these .hash files** to match the name of the .m3u playlist file which every folder also contains.  For example the presence of

> 00 - Revolver.m3u

should cause the hash file to be renamed to

> 00 - Revolver.hash

Does anyone know of a way to do this with a command line? I'm hoping to find something similar to this: [Which command can I use to recursively rename or move a file in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/205083/command-line-recursive-rename-move-in-windows)

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with PowerShell, if you're comfortable with that.

```
function Rename-HashFiles ([string]$path)
{
    [System.IO.FileInfo[]]$hashFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $path -Force -Include "*.hash" -Recurse
    foreach($hashFile in $hashFiles)
    {
        [string]$newFileName = [string]::Empty;
        Get-ChildItem -Path ($hashFile.DirectoryName) -Filter "*.m3u" | % { $newFileName = [System.IO.Path]::GetFileNameWithoutExtension($_.Name) }    
        $newFileName += ([System.IO.Path]::GetExtension($hashFile.Name))
        Rename-Item -Path $hashFile.FullName -NewName $newFileName
    }

}

Rename-HashFiles "C:\My_Music_Folder"
```