# Renaming set of files in multiple folders in Windows command line

Tags: windows, rename, filenames, ms-dos

I have a 320 folders each having a set of two files:

- FilenameA.wav
- FilenameB.txt.

In each folder, I want to rename the .wav file based on the name of the .txt file in the same folder:

```
FilenameA.wav renamed to FilenameB.wav
```

Can I do this with a single command line to handle the renaming in all of the folders?

Comment: yes you should be able to, i'm not good at cmd but this site is good. see Ren for a start example;- https://ss64.com/nt/

Comment: This already has an answer at https://superuser.com/questions/280559/recursively-renaming-foo-files-based-on-name-of-accompanying-bar-file-in-multi