# Recursively rename files through the command line (Windows 7)

Tags: windows-7, command-line, rename

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Which command can I use to recursively rename or move a file in Windows?](https://superuser.com/questions/205083/which-command-can-i-use-to-recursively-rename-or-move-a-file-in-windows)

Is there a way, through the command line, to recursively rename all .m4v files to .avi?

`ren *.m4v *.avi` only works for the folder(s) selected, and ignores the folders under them, and as best I can tell there is no recursive parameter with that function.

Comment: Same question as this: http://superuser.com/questions/205083/command-line-recursive-rename-move-in-windows

Answer (score 44, accepted):

With a for loop, with recursive switch:

```
for /R %x in (*.m4v) do ren "%x" *.avi
```

Comment: I had to use      for /R %G in (*.m4v) do ren "%G" "%~nG*.avi" as in https://ss64.com/nt/for_r.html

Comment: Neither of these work on Windows 11...