# Explode all folders

Tags: macos, filesystems

I've got a folder with about a hundred sub folders and again each ones of those has between 10 and 20 sub folders, so all in all a pretty large folder tree.

Is there a simple way I can explode or export all of the files in the tree to a new folder which will just be one folder contain the files (no folders, no trees)?

I'm running OS X 10.8, although I've also got Parallels so if there is a Windows solution I could just run that as it's not something I need to do everyday.

Comment: Sounds like you need some sort of recursive MV command that moves anything with an extension to a static location. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18295056/batch-file-to-recursively-move-files-to-first-level-directory-from-deeper-subdir http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4357233/move-files-from-the-subfolders-to-the-folders http://superuser.com/questions/205083/which-command-can-i-use-to-recursively-rename-or-move-a-file-in-windows

Answer (score 5):

In OS X, this should work:

```
find /top/source/directory -type f -exec mv {} /destination/directory \;
```

The `find` command searches all subdirectories of the folder `/top/source/directory`, and finds only the files (the option `-type f`). When it finds one it executes (`-exec`) the command `mv` on the file it just found (`{}`) to move it to the new directory, `/destination/directory`.

Please notice that the space before `\;` is absolutely necessary.

Comment: Be warned that this will move all the files, and that they will no longer be in the origanal structure.

Comment: What about overwriting destination files if the filenames are the same?

Comment: if you want to overwrite , use mv -f; if you do not want to overwrite, mv -n; if you want to choose on a case by case basis, mv -i

Answer (score 0):

This should work on the Windows side in **PowerShell**:

`Get-ChildItem -Path "C:\Source" -Recurse -Include *.* | Move-Item -Destination "C:\Destination\"`

Answer (score 0):

This answer is based on Python so it should work on OSX as well as on Windows, assuming you install Python (and for the record, is from the top of my head).

```
import os
import shutil

path = "C:/dir"    # the directory tree you want to "explode"
store= "C:/store"  # where all files will be stored

for dirpath, dirnames, filenames in os.walk(path):

    name = ""
    for c in dirpath:
        if c != "/":    # if the character is different than the current directory character
            name += s
        else:
            name += "_" # "quick and dirty" way of resolving name conflicts

    for files in filenames:

        orig_loc = os.path.join(dirpath,files)
        copy_loc = os.path.join(store,name + "_" + files)
        shutil.copy2(orig_loc,copy_loc)
```

This should copy all files (plus metadata) from the `path` structure to the `store` folder.

If you don't care about name conflicts, don't use the code between the `name = ""` and the `for files in filenames` statements. What that code does is to convert `/` to `_` and afterwards prepend that cleared directory name to the files' names.

This will retain the original structure, that you can delete afterwards with `shutil.rmtree(path)`