# How to recursively copy and rename files in the same directory using Windows command line

Tags: windows, command-line, recursive

I'd like to avoid using a batch file, if possible.

Based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/205089/290707) to a question about [recursive renaming or moving](https://superuser.com/q/205083/290707), I've came up with the following command (for copying all files named web.foo.config to web.config *in the same directory*):

```
for /r %x in (*web.foo.config) do copy /y "%x" web.config
```

However, that just caused every instance of web.foo.config to create and then overwrite .\web.config, not the web.config in the found path. So I tried:

```
for /r %x in (*web.foo.config) do (SET y=%x:foo.config=config% && CALL copy /y "%x" "%y")
```

This has the unfortunate effect of copying the files to a file named "%y".  Is there a way to force `%y` to be evaluated after it's set... or a better method altogether?

Comment: Can you do `xcopy *web.foo.config \destination /S`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Copying all files named web.foo.config to web.config in the same directory**

Since you don't want to use a batch file for this operation then from an elevated command prompt, you can use the below to complete this.

This assumes the directory you are in when you run the command from the command prompt is the one which will be traversed through recursively doing the copy command of the found files.

I left the asterisk (`*`) from the beginning of the `web.foo.config` file name but you can add that where needed if it's really needed to find files with that naming pattern.

**Using Copy Example**

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %F IN ('DIR /B /S web.foo.config') DO COPY /Y "%~F" "%~DPFweb.config"
```

**Using Xcopy Example**

```
FOR /F "TOKENS=*" %F IN ('DIR /B /S web.foo.config') DO ECHO F | XCOPY /Y /F "%~F" "%~DPFweb.config"
```

---

### Further Resources

- [FOR /F](http://ss64.com/nt/for_cmd.html)
- `FOR /?`

  > In addition, substitution of FOR variable references has been
  >   enhanced. You can now use the following optional syntax:
  >
  > ```
  > %~I         - expands %I removing any surrounding quotes (")
  > %~fI        - expands %I to a fully qualified path name
  > %~dI        - expands %I to a drive letter only
  > %~pI        - expands %I to a path only
  > %~nI        - expands %I to a file name only
  > %~xI        - expands %I to a file extension only
  > %~sI        - expanded path contains short names only
  > %~aI        - expands %I to file attributes of file
  > %~tI        - expands %I to date/time of file
  > %~zI        - expands %I to size of file
  > %~$PATH:I   - searches the directories listed in the PATH
  >                environment variable and expands %I to the
  >                fully qualified name of the first one found.
  >                If the environment variable name is not
  >                defined or the file is not found by the
  >                search, then this modifier expands to the
  >                empty string
  > ```

Comment: Thanks, much better than the solution I was about to post: `FOR /R %x IN (*web.foo.config) DO FOR /F "delims=." %y IN ("%x") DO COPY /Y "%x" "%y.config"`, which works as long as there are no periods in the path.

Answer (score 5):

Use xcopy with /S switch to copy all files and directories recursively.

At any Windows command prompt:

```
xcopy *.* \destination /S
```

Quick and easy.

Comment: Does not remotely answer the original question, which was how to recursively copy all files named web.foo.config to web.config in the same directory

Comment: @MikeGodin Can you do `xcopy *web.foo.config \destination /S`?

Comment: The original question was very poorly worded. @Fooze666 answered how to copy recursively, which is exactly what I came here to find. Thanks!