# Rename command cmd wildcard issue

Tags: windows, command-line

I have files like

```
test_abc.html
haha_test_someword.js
haha_morehaha_test_continue_test.someextension
```

I want to replace all test in a particular folder in recursive way to tommy. So the output would become:

```
 tommy_abc.html
    haha_tommy_someword.js
    haha_morehaha_tommy_continue_tommy.someextension
```

Is this possible in command prompt in Windows using ren command?

Answer (score 2):

I do not believe the `ren` command can do what you want on its own, but a batch script that uses `ren` can.

I [answered a very similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47818914/1970593) over on Stack Overflow yesterday. Here is a modified version of that batch script to deal with your problem. It copes with multiple replacements in a single filename:

```
setlocal ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
set SEARCH_TEXT=test
set REPLACE_TEXT=tommy
for %%A in ("*%SEARCH_TEXT%*") do (
    set OLD_NAME=%%~nxA
    set NEW_NAME=!OLD_NAME:%SEARCH_TEXT%=%REPLACE_TEXT%!
    ren "!OLD_NAME!" "!NEW_NAME!"
)
endlocal
```

Again, the help text from the `SET /?` command may be required reading in order to grok this.

Comment: That is a NICE script !

Answer (score 1):

Use a for loop for recursive renaming.
Wildcards for text substitution.

```
for /r %x in (*test*.*) do ren "%x" "*tommy*.*"
```

**Tip:** If running the command once doesn't replace all "test", run the command multiple times or use another for loop.

[How to use wildcards in ren](https://superuser.com/a/475875/853379)

[Recursive ren](https://superuser.com/a/205089/853379)

Comment: Your `FOR` loop does not rename correctly on Win7.1. Did you try it and get it to work? If so, what version of Windows are you using please?

Comment: This doesn't work.

Comment: Error may have been due to `/R` instead of `/r`, also `*tommy*.* ` should have been in quotes.
Try now and see if it works (@wardies). I don't have a windows pc to test this at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Powershell

```
gci "C:\files" | ren -n {$_.Name -replace 'test','tommy'}
```